# Criteria for shard while loading csv file in solr

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper

apache-zookeeper-3.6.1-bin,solr-8.9.0

I have successfully set-up solr-cloud on 2 machines and uploaded configs to zookeeper .Now i have created a collection with numShards=12, replicationFactor=1 and maxShardsPerNode=6
When i loaded a .csv files to solr it is start to distribute data on shards.
What is the criteria on the basis of solr is distributing .csv file among shards? I have not defined any keys for shards.

Comment: This has some useful information on how Solr handles the routing of documents https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/shards-and-indexing-data-in-solrcloud.html#document-routing - I think by default Solr uses the uniqueKey to decide what shard a document goes to (see "router.name" in this page https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_2/collection-management.html#create)